# How to Fill a List of DF with NULL Values if they do not exist in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make list of data frames from some tables that I import into R.

```
#import data
june_loss = read_xlsx()

july_loss =read_xlsx()
...
may_loss = read_xlsx()


#Make List of DataFrmaes
losses_to_be_valued <- list(june_loss, july_loss, ...,may_loss)
```

The problem I am having is that not all of the files exist BUT they could/will in the future so I want the list to remain the same length whether the tables exist or not.

I am looking for a function that will compile the list of data.frames and insert `NULL` where the named variable 'doesn't exist'.

Currently the error in my `lapply` function to fix this says `object 'feb_loss' not found`

```
losses_to_be_valued <- lapply(list(june_loss, july_loss, august_loss, sept_loss,
                                oct_loss, nov_loss, dec_loss, jan_loss,
                                feb_loss, mar_loss, april_loss, may_loss), function(x)   
                                  if(!exists(x))
                                  {assign(x, NULL, envir=.GlobalEnv,inherits = FALSE  )}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I feel dumb and I should because it was an easy fix.

I just put this in the front.

`losses_to_be_valued <- vector(mode = "list",12)`

making this work:

```
#make empty list
losses_to_be_valued <- vector(mode = "list",12)

#import data
june_loss = read_xlsx()

july_loss =read_xlsx()
...
may_loss = read_xlsx()


#Make List of DataFrmaes

losses_to_be_valued <- lapply(list("june_loss", "july_loss", "august_loss", "sept_loss",
                                   "oct_loss", "nov_loss", "dec_loss", "jan_loss",
                                   "feb_loss", 'mar_loss', "april_loss", "may_loss"), function(x)
                                     if(!exists(x, envir=.GlobalEnv))
                                     {assign(x, NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv,inherits = FALSE)}
)

losses_to_be_valued <- list(june_loss, july_loss, ...,may_loss)
```